# How to assign a layer to a group in GDB datasets using gdal python

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, file-geodatabase

I'm currently working with ESRI GDB datasets and I can easily open hierarchical geodatabases and walk the tree using the API that gdal provides.

```py
root_group = ds.GetRootGroup()

for g in root_group.GetGroupNames()
    subgroup = root_group.OpenGroup(g)
    layers = subgroup.GetVectorLayerNames()

    for l in layers:
        ...
```

Now I need to create such hierarchy in a GDB dataset myself but I can't find anything useful in the documentation. Is it possible to create groups and assign layers to them in gdal / ogr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the FEATURE_DATASET= layer creation option (specific of the OpenFileGDB driver) to assign a layer to a feature dataset: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html#layer-creation-options